# Youtube v3 API with browser fetch throws CORS error for "videos"

Tags: javascript, cors, youtube-api

I have something like the following:

```js
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3';

/**
 * @param {string} channelId 
 * @param {string?} pageToken 
 */
const getPlaylist = (channelId, pageToken) => {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=${channelId}&key=${API_KEY}&part=id,snippet&maxResults=50`;
  return pageToken ? `${url}&pageToken=${pageToken}` : url;
};

/**
 * @param {string} playlistId 
 * @param {string?} pageToken 
 */
const getPlaylistItems = (playlistId, pageToken) => {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=${playlistId}&key=${API_KEY}&part=id,snippet&maxResults=50`;
  return pageToken ? `${url}&pageToken=${pageToken}` : url;
}

const getVideo = videoId => `${BASE_URL}/vidoes?part=statistics&id=${videoId}&key=${API_KEY}`;

const fetchViewCountByVideoId = async videoId => {
  const response = await fetch(getVideo(videoId));
  const { statistics: { viewCount } } = await response.json();
  return viewCount;
};
```

So I'm trying to fetch the playlist of a channel, fetch all playlist items in each playlist, get the view count of each item. (I omitted the rest of the code since it works fine.)

The problem is, the first two API batch calls work fine, but when I get to the `videos` API, a CORS error is thrown.

(I am running the code in the browser console because the person who will be using this code is not a programmer, and I don't want to spend time creating a web page and hosting it.)

#### Question

Do I need to sign in for the API calls to work like they should (and use the `authorization` header), or is the response of the `videos` API a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint's [URL](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#request) is:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos`.

But your seems to be:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/vidoes`.

That's a typo, of course. But it'll produce an error:

```bsh
$ wget -O /dev/null "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/vidoes?part=statistics&id=foobar&key=$APP_KEY"
--2020-11-11 01:22:13--  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/vidoes?part=statistics&id=foobar&key=...
Resolving www.googleapis.com (www.googleapis.com)... 216.58.212.138, 172.217.22.10, 172.217.23.106, ...
Connecting to www.googleapis.com (www.googleapis.com)|216.58.212.138|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-11-11 01:22:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

---

Note that if you have a set of video IDs of cardinality `N` -- since the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) of `Videos.list` endpoint can be specified as a comma-separated list of video IDs --, then you may reduce the number of calls to `Videos.list` endpoint from `N` to `floor(N / 50) + (N % 50 ? 1 : 0)` by appropriately using the feature of `id` just mentioned.

---

Yet another thing: since you seems to be interested only by the `viewCount` property, I'll mention also that's a good practice to ask from the API only this info by means of the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) parameter:

`${BASE_URL}/videos?part=statistics&fields=statistics/viewCount&id=${videoId}&key=${API_KEY}`.